# How come the Debug.Assert line causes a compile error in release mode?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm surprised to get a compile error in release mode with the following code.

I have a DEBUG only function declared

```
#If DEBUG Then
Private Function DEBUG_Check() As Boolean
    'Do some checks
    If (checks OK) Return True Else Return False
End Function
#End If
```

Then in the code I use it in a Debug.Assert() as follow:

```
Debug.Assert(DEBUG_Check())
```

I get a compilation error "DEBUG_Check is not declared"
I thought calls to Debug.Assert were completely removed from Release compile?

Comment: Welcome @JBB to SO, for posting your code please use the tool bar button `{}`, I modified your code right now.

Comment: Kalyan - your edits changed the posted code by removing the # from the #If tag.  I have voted to reject that change because editing should not change the posted code, only fix formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you've wrapped your code within compiler tags:

```
#If DEBUG Then
#End If
```

These tags tell the compiler to completely skip the code within the tag if DEBUG is not defined, which it is not in release mode, so in release mode there is no such code as DEBUG_Check().

Related to the later comments:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttcc4x86.aspx

This article is self conflicting.  At one point it says:

> Debug class methods are not included in a Release version of your program, so they do not increase the size or reduce the speed of your release code.

Later, however, it says:

> When you run this code under the debugger, the assertion statement is
>   evaluated, but in the Release version, the comparison is not made, so
>   there is no additional overhead.

My interpretation is that Debug.Assert(params) is still called but to an empty shell method in release as opposed to a functional method in Debug mode.  As such, parameters passed must still be valid.

Comment: He could also move the preprocessor flags inside the method and return false just before the `End Function`.  That way, the checks only occur in `DEBUG` and the function returns false for all other instances that `DEBUG` is not defined.

Comment: I agree, he could do that - although the wording you used implies that I offered a solution, which I did not, to which you're offering an alternative.  I only answered the question asked pertaining to why it happens. ;)  Actually, I think your response deserves to be its own answer.

Comment: hah! I did make it sound like I was adding to your answer.  I began an answer explaining the `ConditionalAttribute("DEBUG")` that annotates `Debug.Assert` and changed my mind because calling `Debug.Assert()` with some method that only returns true in `DEBUG` is overly redundant.

Comment: I understand that my DEBUG_Check function is not compiled in release mode and that's the behaviour I want. What I was also hoping was that all call to Debug.Assert(XYZ) would be excluded from release compiles. It doesn't seem to be the case since the compilation fails when the DEBUG_Check is not present. I don't understand that behaviour.

Comment: In release mode the comparisons aren't made - but the code call to Debug.Assert is still there in your code, so presumably Debug classes in release mode are just empty shells.  The compiler itself doesn't know that Debug.Assert should be deleted at compilation w/o the compilation flags.

Comment: Added some links to my answer.

Comment: Thanks guys. I guess Debug.Assert in release mode is "just an empty shell" like you said. I went for the solution of placing my #IF DEBUG within my DEBUG_Check function and just returning True if DEBUG not defined. Not ideal solution but works OK.

Comment: You might consider moving your testing out into a dedicated test project that has rights to view internals - that way your assertions can be completely removed from production.  (Think Test Driven Development)